# Cual es el significado del "-" cuando esta al lado de una variable o parametro

Tags: javascript

Estaba leyendo el libro de Eloquent Javascript, y en los ejercicios de Funciones de recursion te hace resolver un problema y esta es la solucion que dan en el libro

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}


console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → false
```

Mi pregunta es que significa el uso de "-n" en esta linea

```
return isEven(-n);
```

y cuales son sus posibles usos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene el mismo valor que en matemáticas en este caso.

Por ejemplo:

Previamente deben haber definido el valor de la variable n, en ese caso, si n = 10, -n = -10, y n-2 = 8.

Ese bucle es un ejercicio recursivo para finalizar, según el valor inicial de n devolviendo una variable booleana a la función isEven. En realidad va a devolver false si n era un número par, y true si era impar.

Comment: ok ok, osea podria decir que si n = -10, -n = 10?

Comment: Si exacto, pero no significa que cualquier valor de n va a cambiar el signo. Sólo si n es negativo, lo cambia a positivo para poder ir restando 2 en cada bucle hasta llegar a 0 o a 1 según el valor inicial de n, y devolver true o false al finalizar la función

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente cambia el signo. Si en la variable `n` tenemos el valor 20, al método `isEven()` se le pasará como parámetro el valor `-20`.

Posibles usos:

- Cambiar el signo del valor de una variable :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, osea funciona como una especie de valor absoluto?. osea si el valor de -n es negativo pasa apositivo y si es positivo pasa a negativo?

Comment: Eso no es así... Ahora publico mi respuesta.

Comment: @MiquelColl el operador `-` hace exactamente lo que se describe en la respuesta (cambiar el signo de la variable y pasarla de negativo a positivo). ¿Por qué dices que es incorrecta?

Comment: Simplemente pone un punto negativo a mi respuesta y él añade una respuesta que no contesta a ninguna pregunta que haya formulado Guillermo. Muy bien Miquel, enhorabuena.

Comment: El dice que si la variable tiene valor `20` lo pasará a `-20` y eso no es así en la función definida. lo que hace es al revés. pasar de -20 a 20 (de cualquier negativo a positivo)

Comment: @MiquelColl ¿Qué mas da? Ha puesto un ejemplo con 20 pasando a -20 como podía haberlo puesto al revés. La realidad es que `-` simplemente cambia el signo, como se indica en esta respuesta

Comment: Estoy poniendo un ejemplo genérico Miquel, como bien dice Álvaro.

Comment: Igualmente, gracias a ese punto negativo de Miquel, la respuesta marcada como correcta ha sido la de Sebastián. Gracias de nuevo Miquel.

Comment: @RogerGarcia eso no es culpa de Miquel. El que decide qué pregunta se acepta es OP, y puede seleccionar una con +20 o una con -10. Puede que Guillermo haya entendido que Sebastián lo explicaba mejor.

Comment: ¡de nada! No quería que que el autor se liara pensando que de un valor positivo pasava a negativo... No está de más adaptarse al contexto (des de mi punto de vista, que es lo único que es, un punto de vista). Es mi opinión, nada más. Lo siento si no estáis de acuerdo y respeto vuestra opinión.

Comment: Tienes razón Álvaro. Disculpas. Un saludo a ambos.

Comment: @RogerGarcia siento que te lo tomes mal. ¿Por qué no editas tu respuesta para que tenga sentido en el contexto de Guillermo? Entonces sí que tendría sentido para mi :) No tienes por qué ni te lo exijo ni nada eh, simplemente lo comento! Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Para ser corto:

un signo `-` delante de una variable *numérica* lo que hace es cambiar de signo esa variable.

Es decir, si la variable es positiva, pasa a negativa. Si la variable es negativa, pasa a positiva. Ejemplo:

`n = 5` implica que `-n = -5`

`n = -5` implica que `-n = 5`

---

**Respuesta original**

En la función definida `isEven` utiliza recursividad para los números naturales i **positivos**.

Fíjate que tenemos 4 casos definidos en la función. 2 bases y 2 de continuación.

En los dos casos base se define la finalización de la función, dónde si se llega con `n=0` entonces devuelve `true` y si se llega con `n=1` se devuelve `false`.

El funcionamiento de la función en sí es ir llamando a al misma función restándole 2 a cada iteración hasta que llegue a `0` o `1` (lo que hace la última función).

Cómo sólo esta definido por números **positivos** hay un caso base de **entrada** que llama a la función `isEven` si el número que queremos es negativo. Para poner un ejemplo:

- Partimos de `n=5`:

1a iteración: Se llama a `isEven(3)`

2a iteración: Se llama a `isEven(1)`

3a iteración: Cómo `n=1` devuelve `false`.

- Si partimos de cualquier número negativo, por ejemplo, `n=-5`, que es el caso concreto que preguntas:

1a iteración: Se llama a `isEven(5)`

2a iteración: Se llama a `isEven(3)`

3a iteración: Se llama a `isEven(1)`

4a iteración: Cómo `n=1` devuelve `false`.

Por lo que hacer un `isEven` de un número negativo es **lo mismo** que hacer un `isEven` del mismo número pero en positivo (y con 1 nivel más de recursividad).

De las 3 funciones de ejemplo que dan en el libro la última `console.log(isEven(-1));` es la única que entra en ese caso específico (`n<0`) y entonces llama a `isEven(1)`

---

Para finalizar simplemente comentar que es **mucho más fácil** utilizar el **módulo** para calcular si un número es par o impar:

```
function isEven(n) 
{
    return n%2==0;
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta explica cómo funciona el método `isEven` pero no para qué sirve el `-` delante de una variable que es la pregunta de OP.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón, me he ido por las ramas explicando la función y me he olvidado de la pregunta específica. ¡Editado! y gracias :)